# Global Site Tag and Adwords/Analytics

Tags: gtag.js

We are using Google Tag Manager on SOME of our sites, but not all.  On the others, we are using the Global Site Tag (with UA-), like below:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - AdWords: 1234567890 --> <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1234567890"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-1234567890');
</script>
```

HOWEVER, when we look at our Adwords account it says to use this tag (with AW-):

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - AdWords: 1234567890 --> <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1234567890"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-1234567890');
</script>
```

I've seen some videos and posts saying "if you're using either one of these, that's all you need".  Is that true?

I have also seen a post that says you need two tags in it (UA- and AW-), as below:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - AdWords: 1234567890 --> <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1234567890"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-1234567890');
  gtag('config', 'UA-1234567890');

</script>
```

I'd love to find out which is true, and as a result, which we should be using.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The last example you mention is the correct one. Anyway I would put the Google Analytics ID as a parameter as mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/):

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA-PROPERTY_ID"> 
</script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'GA-PROPERTY_ID');
    gtag('config', 'AW-GOOGLE_CONVERSION_ID');
</script>
```